# How to "not" consume all the budget at early stage on a day at Google Adwords?

Tags: google-adwords

Let me introduce me with greetings since I am new here.

I am currently setting up the budget of Google Adwords at 200 dollars at a day. ( Say, 6,000 USD a month. )

Although, I am Japanese and the words may be different in English version, let me ask here since we don't have a specific oriented site in our country.

I am setting the target time zone at from around 10am to 21 am ( around ) every day.

But the huge flux of clicks eats all the budget set to each day and we are unable to display the campaign at the later stage of a day.

Is this a mistake of the portfolio management?

Or since I struck a new campaign, is the Adwords still "learning"? ( Some words already have the quality score of 7 but others 1-2, although click percentage is over 2%. )

Should I wait for sometime or do something else?

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would do is check out your delivery option settings.    There are two delivery methods, accelerated and standard.

Standard delivery will try and spend your budget evenly through the day, and accelerated tries to spend as quickly as possible.    If a new campaign and set to standard and are experiencing this, Google may be learning.   If it's set to accelerated change the setting and see if this solves the problem.

If you are on standard delivery you may have to get creative.   You could try adding bid adjustments so you bid less at earlier hours of the day.   This may stretch your budget further into the day, and let you win clicks at a lower cost per click.

If you want more even pacing you could duplicate the campaign, and set them each to run in different hours of the day, and split the budget.

Last option would be to increase your budget, but if it were that easy, I'm sure you would have done that.